# document.ready is being called after re-render of the page also

Tags: jquery

I have a small single page application where, I wrote document.ready to start an event.

But, to my surprise, everytime page re-renders because of any button click , document.ready is getting called. Please help me regarding this

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "styles/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/code.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log( "ready!" );
            renderOldTweets();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="images/twitter_name.png" class="twitter-img">
            <span>Twitter Clone</span></p>
        </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content" class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div id="createTweet" class="create-tweet-cont">
        <h2>Create a Tweet</h2>
        <form id = "tweetform" onsubmit="submitTweet()">
            <textarea name="text" id="tweetarea" placeholder ="Say what you feel!!" class="tweetText"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Tweet!" class="tweet-button"></button>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to prevent the form from being submitted and reloading the page

Comment: Can u please share whats in code.js?

Comment: Why are you surprised? That is what document.ready does. What do you expect to happen when you click a button? I assume it is submit since I don't see any other buttons.